# Getting Python to Confirm If/Elif/Else before proceeding

Tags: python, if-statement

I've written a simple python script to take command line arguments and write them to a file for deployment to a router using Ansible. But before my script creates that output file, I want to force the user to confirm the request with a Y/N (Yes or No) entry.

How can I modify this script to request that after each if/elif statement?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--set", help="set", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--delete", help="delete", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ipaddr", help="Target IP")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.set:
        print "Deploying: set routing-options static route %s" % (args.ipaddr)
        filename = open("/var/tmp/output.txt",'w')
        sys.stdout = filename
        print "set routing-options static route %s" % (args.ipaddr)
elif args.delete:
        print "Deploying: delete routing-options static route %s" % (args.ipaddr)
        filename = open("/var/tmp/output.txt",'w')
        sys.stdout = filename
        print "delete routing-options static route %s" % (args.ipaddr)
else:
        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a `ask_confirm` function and call it wherever needed:

```
def ask_confirm(msg="Are you sure?"):
    answer = ""
    while answer not in ("yes", "no"):
        answer = input(msg + " [yes/no]")
    return (True if answer == "yes" else False)
```

The default value of `msg` lets you call `ask_confirm` with a generic message.
It returns a boolean value so it is easier to handle.
The inputs could be customized in a fancier way if needed.
Here is a fancier version:

```
def ask_confirm(msg="Are you sure?", yes=None, no=None):
    if yes is None:
        yes = ["yes"]
    if no is None:
        no = ["no"]
    if isinstance(yes, str):
        yes = [yes]
    if isinstance(no, str):
        no = [no]

    answer = ""
    while answer not in yes and answer not in no:
        answer = input(msg + " [{}/{}]".format(yes[0], no[0]))
    return (True if answer in yes else False)
```

Then you can ask for confirmation at the beginning of each block:

```
if args.set:
    if not ask_confirm("Do you really want to set?"):
        sys.exit()
    # else (not needed)
    # proceed

elif args.delete:
    if not ask_confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"):
        sys.exit()
    # else (not needed)
    # proceed

else:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I gave the fancier option a try and it seems like it got stuck in a loop and never proceeded. I had to Control-C out of it. []$ ./test.py -s -i 10.0.0.1
Do you really want to set? [yes/no]yes
Do you really want to set? [yes/no]^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 29, in <module>
    if not ask_confirm("Do you really want to set?"):
  File "./test.py", line 24, in ask_confirm
    answer = input(msg + " [{}/{}]".format(yes[0], no[0]))
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: @Alby, Hum, I just tried it and it works as expected. How did you try it exactly?

Comment: I used the non-fancy option and got this error:  []$ ./test.py -s -i 10.0.0.1
Do you really want to set? [yes/no]yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 36, in <module>
    if not ask_confirm("Do you really want to set?"):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in ask_confirm
    answer = input(msg + " [yes/no]")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I'm using Python 2.7.5

Comment: @Alby Could you try and add `print(answer); print(answer in yes); print(answer in no)` right after the `answer = input(...)` in the `ask_confirm` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152847/discussion-between-right-leg-and-alby).

Comment: Right Leg, thanks for all your help. I decided to do some revision and opted to add a simple   raw_input("Enter to Confirm/Control-C to Exit...")  to just pause the if/elif and require the user to hit enter to continue or Control-C out of the script. But thanks for everything, it helped enlighten my python knowledge.